# How to define stricter typing in child class inherited methods in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

Assume I have three classes like so.

```
abstract class A {
   abstract protected function doSomething($object): array;
}

class B extends A {
   protected function doSomething(SomeObject $object): array
   {
       // something
   }
}

class C extends A {
   protected function doSomething(OtherObject $object): array
   {
       // something
   }
}
```

According to principles of inheritance as PHP does it, the structure described above is not legal PHP code, as the method definitions are not compatible with the base class. I can, of course, do something like

```
class B extends A {
    protected function doSomething($object): array
    {
        if (!is_a($object, 'SomeObject')) {
            throw new Exception('Object passed to method is not of the correct class for this method.');
        }

        // something
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if there is another solution to implementing a method in an abstract class that can be redefined to only accept objects of specific type in it.

Comment: your objects could implement the same interface, you can then pass the interface as the argument type

Comment: Making the arguments of a subclass narrower/more specific than the base class arguments is a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle, which says that if a method in superclass A accepts an argument of class B and returns an object of class C, then a subclass of A that reimplements the method can only modify things such that the argument can be a superclass of class B (contravariance) and the return type can be a subclass of class C (covariance)

Answer (score 5):

You can't without implementing it yourself in similar way than in your example.

PHP support for covariance and contravariance [is clearly defined](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php):

> Covariance allows a child's method to return a more specific type than the return type of its parent's method. Whereas, **contravariance allows a parameter type to be less specific in a child method, than that of its parent**.

If a child class were capable of having stricter parameter requirements than its parent or interface, this would lead to broken expectations.

For example: let's say that you have the following:

```
abstract class AbstractParam{}

class ParamOne extends AbstractParam{}
class ParamTwo extends AbstractParam{}
class ParamThree extends AbstractParam{}

abstract class AbstractService {

    abstract public function foo(AbstractParam $bar);
}
```

Any time you would need to use an implementation of this service, you would do so with the assurance that passing any valid instance of  `AbstractParam` to `foo()` would be legal. The method signature is clearly communicating this.

If I could change this on inheritance/implementation, and suddenly I could change `foo()` signature to:

```
public function foo(ParamOne $bar)
```

The contract would be broken, and you couldn't depend on `AbstractService` safely, since there would be no longer possible to pass any  `AbstractParam` instance to `foo()`, thus [violating the LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in the process: You could no longer substitute objects of the base class with objects that belong to a subtype of that base object while maintaining correctness.

The approach in your question would work, but I don't think it's a great design for the above reasons. If you really must go that way, simply remove the type hint from method definition:

```
abstract class AbstractService {

    abstract public function foo($bar);
}

class ConcreteService extends AbstractService {
    public function foo($bar) {}
}
```

But it's probably better to rethink why you actually need this, and try to retain type-safety.

Comment: Actually, if I look at the link you provided, I see that 7.4 allowed co- and contravariance. The server runs 7.0, sadly, but this is very useful nonetheless!

Comment: Glad you found it useful. In any event the answer remains the same, even on 7.0. It's not that "there is no way", but "there shouldn't be a way because it would break things" :)